Show/hide element based on URL matching in Javascript
total newbie here, first try to get a script to work for an a/b-test.
I have one element, 'prodBanEle', that I want to be seen only if up to three other URLs (topBanUrl1, topBanUrl2, topBanUrl3) in another element also present on the page is a part of the current URL.
So for example: if you visit "mywebsite.com/category-grey-pants/product-light-grey-shorts/", 'prodBanEle' should only be visible if "mywebsite.com/category-grey-pants/" is one of the three URLs.
If the current URL instead is "mywebsite.com/category-shorts/product-light-grey-shorts/", 'prodBanEle' should not be visible.
This is what I've tried to get to work, the thing I'm most uncertain of is indexOf actually works with variables or only strings. But I'm sure there are a bunch of other mistakes in there...
$(function(){
    var prodBanEle = document.getElementById("addToCardButtonDiv").getElementsByClassName("banner ")[0];
    var topBanUrl1 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_1");
    var topBanUrl2 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_2");
    var topBanUrl3 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_3");
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(topBanUrl1)){
                prodBanEle.style.display = "block";
        } 
        else if (window.location.href.indexOf(topBanUrl2)){
                prodBanEle.style.display = "block";
        }
        else if (window.location.href.indexOf(topBanUrl3)){
                prodBanEle.style.display = "block";
        }
        else { prodBanEle.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  );

Are there any obvious mistakes the you recognize immediately, or should it work?
Thank you for your help!

if you use indexOf like that, you will have to add !== -1 at the end of each condition. indexOf can return 0 when the first element matches the argument. 0 evaluates to false in an if.

Please include the relevant html.

Side note: you could improve readability by combining the 3 statements that set display: block; using an or (||) operator instead.

Also you comparing a string (href) property to a node. Maybe you ment the value or inner text of the node?

window.location.href is a string, while topBanUrl1 (and the other two) are HTMLElements. You likely want the .textContent of those elements. I'd also use includes instead of indexOf for ease of use.

And if you're using .textContent don't forget to .trim() it as it will include the whitespace from the original (no-doubt-) nicely laid out HTML.


Don't mix jQuery and DOM like that - I changed to plain JS
Cache the value to not keep requesting it
I assume document.getElementById("top_banner_url_1") is a link with an href? Or .textContent?
I use .some, which will return true if any of the URLs are included the href

I can answer better if I see some HTML
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let prodBanEle = document.getElementById("addToCardButtonDiv").querySelector(".banner");
  let topBanIDs = ["top_banner_url_1", "top_banner_url_2", "top_banner_url_3"];
  let href = window.location.href;
  prodBanEle.hidden = !topBanIDs.some(id => href.includes(document.getElementById(id).href)); // assuming a link, if not use .textContent
});


One possible mistake is
topBanUrl1, topBanUrl2, and topBanUrl3 should be strings not elements since you use indexOf.
I don't know what the html is, but instead of
var topBanUrl1 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_1");
var topBanUrl2 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_2");
var topBanUrl3 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_3");

it would be this assuming that top_banner_url_1, top_banner_url_2, top_banner_url_3 are links
var topBanUrl1 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_1").href;
var topBanUrl2 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_2").href;
var topBanUrl3 = document.getElementById("top_banner_url_3").href;


Some of the most important DOM methods to know are .querySelector() and .querySelectorAll(). With the former you can find a single element (specifically the first one if there is more than one). With the latter, you can find multiple elements as a NodeList which can be converted into an array (which is easier to work with).
Usage:
Pass a CSS selector string to target any element(s).
<a id="x1" class="link" name="xLink"></a>
<a id="x2" class="link" name="xLink"></a>
<a id="x3" class="link" name="xLink"></a>


Find the second link by id prefix with #:
 document.querySelector("#x2")


Find all links by class prefix with .:
 document.querySelectorAll(".link")


Find all links by tag:
 document.querySelectorAll("a")


Find all links by other attributes [attribute='value']:
 document.querySelectorAll("[name='xLink']")



A NodeList from .querySelectorAll() can be converted to an array with either the Array method Array.from():
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
const newArray = Array.from(nodeList);

Or with the spread operator:
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
const newArray = [...nodeList];

In the example below is a function that'll hide one or more elements if a given url or a part thereof isn't found in the href of at least one of a given group of <a>nchors.
Note:

Ternaries are used throughout the function

Methods .forEach(), .some(), and .includes() are used

Property .link is used to make a HTMLCollection of all <a>


Details are commented in the example and every step at runtime is logged to console.
Example:


// For demo purposes
const log = data => console.log(data);

/**
 * Targets one or more HTML elements to hide if a given url 
 * isn't found in the href of one or more anchors and vice 
 * versa.
 * @param targets a CSS selector string to target the elements
 * @param url     the url (or fragment of a url) string to find
 * @param anchors the CSS selector string of one or more
 *                anchors to search through
 *                if nothing is assigned, all of the anchors
 *                will be searched
 */
function hideElementsIfNoURL(targets, url, anchors) {
  let present;
  /* 
  A array of elements that will be hidden if the given url
  isn't present.
  */
  let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(targets)];
  log(">>> Array: elements");
  log(elements);

  /*
  An array of anchors in which to search for the given url.
  If the parameter wasn't passed, then all the anchors on the
  page will be in array linx.
  */
  let linx = typeof anchors === "string" ?
    [...document.querySelectorAll(anchors)] :
    [...document.links];
  log(">>> Array: linx");
  log(linx);

  /*
  .some() will iterate over array linx until it finds a 
  condition to be true in which it returns true, otherwise,
  it will return false. The condition is determined by
  running .includes() over each href of each anchor.
  */
  log(">>> Iterating over Array: linx");
  present = linx.some((a, i) => {
    log(`${i} href='${a.href}'`);
    return a.href.includes(url);
  });
  log(">>> Is the URL present?");
  log(`Boolean: present = ${present}`);

  /*
  .forEach() iterates over array elements and assigns "none"
  to each element's display style if present is false or
  nothing if present is true.
  */
  log(">>> Iterating over Array: elements");
  elements.forEach(e => {
    let hide = present ? "" : "none";
    e.style.display = hide;
    log(e);
  });
  log(">>> If the URL wasn't found, then each element should have:");
  log(`style="display: none"`);
  log(">>> END <<<");
}

/**
 * Hide class="banner1" if any <a> inside class="links1"
 * doesn't have the URL.
 */
hideElementsIfNoURL(".banner1", "example.com/category-grey-pants/", ".links1 a");

/**
 * Hide <h1> if the URL can't be found in any <a> on the
 * page.
 */
hideElementsIfNoURL("h1", "/category-shoes");

/**
 * Hide class="headliner" if the URL isn't in any <a> 
 * within class="links2".
 */
hideElementsIfNoURL(".headliner", "/category-shoes", ".links2 a");
header,
menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

header {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

menu {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 40% !important;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  content: "" !important;
}
<header>
  <h1>Pants Emporium</h1>
  <nav>
    <menu class="links1 links">
      <p class="headliner">We have pants!</p>
      <li><a href="https://example.com/category-black-pants/">Black Pants</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://example.com/category-khaki-pants/">Khaki Pants</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://example.com/category-grey-pants/">Grey Pants</a></li>
    </menu>
  </nav>
  <menu class="banner1 banner">
    <button type="button">Add to Cart 1</button>
  </menu>
</header>

<header>
  <h1>Pants Emporium</h1>
  <p class="headliner">We have pants!</p>
  <nav>
    <menu class="links2 links">
      <li><a href="https://example.com/category-black-pants/">Black Pants</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://example.com/category-khaki-pants/">Khaki Pants</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://example.com/category-grey-pants/">Grey Pants</a></li>
    </menu>
  </nav>
  <menu class="banner2 banner">
    <button type="button">Add to Cart 2</button>
  </menu>
</header>



